# angular2 rc4 migration to rc5 causing issues

Tags: angular

When I migrate my app from rc4 to rc5, I get the following error.

[image]

Here is my main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app.module.ts';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

[ng severing console working properly but browser showing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaxMz.png)

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, the issue isn't with your main.ts, but with your app.module.ts. We need more information to be able to help you out.

Comment: You need to copy your error output and paste it here. Do not just give an image.

Comment: Are you sure that you have `app.module.ts`?

Comment: yes i'm sure this is app.module.ts code     import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'


@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports:      [BrowserModule, 
    HttpModule, // provides HTTP_PROVIDERS
    ],
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule{}

Comment: If you're using Chrome, got to the network tab in dev tools and check 'Disable cache' and then try a hard refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the .ts extensions from your imports:

Should be:

```
import { AppModule }              from './app.module';
```

Comment: still same problem . either remove or not ts extemsion

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .ts extension from app.module.ts and make sure your main.ts and app.module.ts are on the same folder.

Comment: i have removed extension and both of files are in same folder.but still nit working